# Tailwind CSS text and image on same line?

Tags: css

Using [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/utility-first)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link href="tailwind.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<p>With TailwindCss before<img src='at.png'>after.com</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Produces:

[image: With Tailwind CSS]

with the link removed:

```
<link href="tailwind.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

it produces:

[image: Without Tailwind CSS]

What is needed to get the Tailwind CSS version to match the original where the text and image are on the same line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They must include a rule to make images display as block elements.  The rule would look something like:

```css
img {display:block}
```

If you wanted to override this, you could include your own custom rule to set images back to inline display:

```css
img {display:inline}
```

Alternately, you could use a [tailwinds defined class](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/display) on your image to make that particular image inline:

```html
<p>With TailwindCss before<img class=inline src='at.png'>after.com</p>
```

Comment: class=i'nline' is what I am looking for.

Comment: Just to clarify, Tailwind *does* (quite rudely) change all `img` tags ... and all `svg`, `video`, `canvas`, `audio`, `iframe`, `embed`, and `object` tags ... to be `display:block`.  You can find the code in `node_modules/tailwindcss/src/css/preflight.css`.